# Z-score transformation for joint cluster analyses

Tags: clustering

I am dealing with a situation where I need to use a joint matrix of approximately gaussian distributed data (limits - Inf to + Inf) and beta-distributed data (both produced using different experimental methods for the same samples) to generate clusters. So far I have tried clustering a Random Forest proximity matrix , and the thing that works best is an unconventional approach where I do not model the proximity matrix explicitly as a dissimilarity.

I am looking for advice on whether transforming everything to approximately Gaussian using either Z-scores or a logit transform of the beta-distributed variables is a good way of creating a matrix suitable for direct clustering.

Comment: Unclear, for me. Are you going to do cluster analysis or to generate clusters?

Comment: If the attributes are approximately Gaussian / approximately beta distributed, then there shouldn't be any clusters there!

Comment: A) I am looking to generate clusters
B) There are 1259 features across 145 samples - each one of them is approximately Gaussian or beta distributed  - but there are clear clustering patterns visible in each of the datasets - a heatmap with Hierarchical clustering dendrograms confirms this.